# I want to next video play when first video was ended in Processing 3.5.3

Tags: video, processing

I want to play the multiple video one by one, It was working. But the video was actually not finished. I check the video duration, and it is correct however the video not finished. I think video is slowly than original video. I don't know why it is that. That original video takes 31s, but it shows about 21s, but duration was 31s. video size is 17.5 MB/mp4.

I using window notebook.

```html
import processing.video.*;

int stage;

Movie intro02;

void setup() {
  size(1920, 1080);

  intro02 = new Movie(this, "002_intro_sound_41.mp4");

  noStroke();
  noCursor();

  frameRate(30);

  stage = 1;
}

void movieEvent(Movie m) {
  m.read();
}

void draw() {
  switch(stage) {
  case 0 :
    intro02.play();
    image(intro02, 0, 0, width, height);
    if (intro02.time() > intro02.duration() - 0.1) {
      stage = 1;
    }
    break;
  case 1 :
    intro02.stop();
    oni01.play();
    index = 0;
    stage = 2;
    break;
```

Comment: That doesn't sound like a Processing problem, but a problem with your video file. What do real video players like VLC or MPC-HD say its duration is?

Comment: its duration is 31 seconds in real video file.

Comment: So then your problem isn't the code you've written, is Processing claiming that your video is 21 seconds long. That sounds like a problem with `processing.video.Movie`, have you checked [their issue tracker](https://github.com/processing/processing-video/issues) or the main [processing issue tracker](https://github.com/processing/processing/issues) for known bugs around Processing incorrectly determining movie duration? And if you couldn't find any, did you post one?

Comment: umm.....no......I just searching the problem that similar error. But I didn't search that. So, I question about it in.

Comment: Right, but remember that stackoverflow is for when you're run out of place to ask, so when dealing with questions about open source software, _always_ at the very least ask the people who make that open source software. Then if they don't respond, or they don't know, Stackoverflow is a good place to ask. And some open source project use Stackoverflow as the place to ask questions, in which case posting here first makes sense, but that's not the case for Processing. So keep your question open here, but _also_ ask on those issue trackers because that's the most authoritative place to get answers

Comment: @suhyunkim I've noticed the same problem with the `Movie` class incorrectly reporting `duration()`, As your code above already suggests, using an offset (`0.1`) in your example should do the trick. You can see an [older answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31832499/playing-multiple-videos-in-processing/31916948#31916948) which uses `0.029719` instead, however, that value from what I could observe depends on each video.